# Field Analysis UI for Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

Solr has this beautiful analysis tool for trying different field types and analyzers without having to go through index/query cycle.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/analysis-screen.html

Is there something similar for Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not have any such UI for the analysis.
Elasticsearch provides an API for analysis and responds in the json format.

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "Quick Brown Foxes!"
}
```

another API is :

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "standard",
  "filter" : ["snowball"],
  "text" : "detailed output",
  "explain" : true,
  "attributes" : ["keyword"] 
}
```